# Does there exist an element of order $4$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})/GL_2(\mathbb{Z})'$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, general-linear-group, derived-subgroup

For a group $G$, let $G'$ denote the commutator of the group $G$, and if $H \leq G$ the left cosets will be denoted as $gH$. Now, I understand the fact that $[SL_2(\mathbb{Z}):GL_2(\mathbb{Z})'] = 2.$

My question is:

> Does there exist an element of order $4$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})/GL_2(\mathbb{Z})'$?

What I have worked out so far is that all the elements of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ that have order $4$ will have $i$ and $-i$ as their eigenvalues. Since order of $gH$ divides order of $g$, the existence of an element of order $4$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})/GL_2(\mathbb{Z})'$ would make it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

So my rephrased question is as follows:

> Is $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})/GL_2(\mathbb{Z})' \cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}? $

Comment: An answer was given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4862456/what-is-the-abelianization-of-operatornameautf-2) in the comments, but has been deleted.

Comment: @DietrichBurde What a pity! It happens too often. Does your high reputation allow you to see deleted comments? Or do you remember that one enough to report it?

Comment: @AnneBauval No, I cannot see the comment, but it was along the lines of Derek's answer. One could also use more general tools of homological algebra to compute $H_1(G,\Bbb Z)$ via Mayer-Vietoris, because $GL_2(\Bbb Z)=D_4\ast_{D_2} D_6$, and then have $GL_2(\Bbb Z)/GL_2(\Bbb Z)'\cong H_1(GL_2(\mathbb Z),\Bbb Z)\cong C_2\times C_2
$, but it is certainly better to compute it directly.

Comment: Is $D_4 *_{D_2} D_6$ in some sense a fiber product/pull-back?

Comment: It is a [free product with amalgamation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product#Generalization:_Free_product_with_amalgamation).

Comment: Okay thank you.

Comment: Note that once you know you can write the group as $D_8\ast_{D_4}D_{12}$, the abelianization is easy since it's the central product $$ D_8/D_8'\times_{D_4/D_4'}D_{12}/D_{12}'$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

${\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ (or ${\rm GL}_2({\mathbb Z})$ if you prefer) is defined to be the multiplicative group of $2 \times 2$ invertible matrices over ${\mathbb Z}$ or,  equivalently, matrices over ${\mathbb Z}$ with determinant $\pm 1$.

A presentation of ${\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$, which I believe comes from the paper T. Brady, Automatic structures on Aut($F_2)$, Arch. Math. 63, 97-102 (1994), is
$$\langle P,S,U| P^2, S^2, (SP)^4, (UPSP)^2,
   (UPS)^3, (US)^2 \rangle,$$
(where ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z}) = \langle PS,U\rangle$) from which you can calculate that $G/[G,G] \cong C_2 \times C_2$, so the answer to your question is no.

*Added later*: I should have said that an isomorphism from the group defined by the above presentation to ${\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ is defined by
$$P \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{rr}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right),\ \ 
S \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{rr}-1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right),\ \ 
U \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{rr}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right).
$$

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @Derek Holt: is an explicit matrix of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ which does not lie in $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})'$ ? Do we have a nice characterization of matrices of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ which belong to $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: Thank you for the explicit generators, but what I meant was much simpler: the definition $G:={\rm GL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ is missing. Or $G:=\langle P,S,U\mid\dots\rangle$

Comment: @GreginGre 1) $PS$ 2) $SL\subset GL$.

Comment: I meant $GL'_2(\mathbb{Z})$, sorry

Comment: @GreginGre Then 2): $GL'\subseteq SL$, so what you are asking is whether we have a nice characterization of the elements of $GL'_2(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Exactly. Maybe in terms of trace values ?

Comment: @GreginGre No idea. I think this question should not be a comment but a new post.